# Chef Recipe: File not found issue (does not contain a file at any of these locations)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm trying to bootstrap a machine with a recipe that contains a call to **cookbook_ file** resource with `action:create`. The following issue occurs during execution (some information has been redacted):

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound: cookbook_file[/path/to/file]
(XXXX::default line 25) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound:
Cookbook 'XXXX' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these
locations:   files/default/file   files/second_folder/file
```

I checked my `/chef/cookbooks/cookbook_name/recipe/files/default` and `/second_folder` directories, and the files required are there, but Chef is just refusing to recognize them. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you  share your cookbook_file usage? This will help helping with your issue

Answer (score 1):

> **Default folder solution**

Your source file `file` should be placed on your cookbook at:

```
cookbook_name/files/default/file
```

Then you should use the **cookbook_file** as follow:

```
cookbook_file "/home/user/file") do
   source 'file'
   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0644'
   action :create
end
```

---

> **Custom folder solution**

You can also place your `file` on a different folder from default one as your **second_folder** for example:

```
cookbook_name/files/second_folder/file
```

This way you should specify on source also the not default directory as follow:

```
cookbook_file "/home/user/file") do
   source 'second_folder/file'
   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0644'
   action :create
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ignore files you might have inherited from cookbook template. In my case the error was to not able finding an `xml` file and I had `*.xml` in both ignore files `chefignore` and `.gitignore`